# Can you run Ubuntu Server from a Desktop computer?

Tags: 12.10, server

I dont have an actual server, am i able to run Ubuntu server 12.10 on a desktop computer?

Comment: Why do you want a Server system? Ubuntu desktop has all the abilities of a server system, but is configured to be more responsive when used by a local/remote user. If you edit to add exactly what you need, I could tell you if you should use Desktop or server edition.

Comment: @DavidKohen The difference between desktop and server responsiveness were a consequence of different kernel compilation options (primarily the size of the [time quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing))). That no longer applies as of Ubuntu 12.04--[in 12.04 and later versions, the desktop and server kernels are the same](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F). Therefore, unless someone is using an old version, what you've brought up here is *not* a consideration.

Comment: Still, the differences in the editions does not limit one from using a "desktop" edition as a server, and that's why I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Ubuntu server will run fine on a desktop computer.

RAM and CPU power as well as HDD size will depend on what you actually want to run on the server. But Ubuntu server editions works perfectly on a desktop computer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works. I've tried it on my Laptop and everything is fine. You can install all normal packages like openssh, apache2 and lots more.